# Trouble with a triple integral on a region bounded by a sphere and two planes

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> I would like to compute the integral $\int_A zdzdydx,$ where $A$ is the region bounded by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2,$ plane $\frac{x}a+\frac{y}b=1$ and coordinate planes (which doesn't contain the origin on its boundary and is in the first quadrant).

I considered switching to either spherical or cylindrical coordinates, but I don't see any symmetry or pattern.

In spherical coordinates, I tried expressing the lower bound for radius $r$ in terms of $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ $$r(\theta, \varphi)=\frac{ab}{a\sin\varphi\sin\theta+b\cos\varphi\sin\theta}$$  and the integral becomes

\begin{aligned}&\color{white}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\frac{ab}{a\sin\theta\sin\varphi+b\sin\theta\cos\varphi}}^Rr^2\sin\theta r\cos\theta drd\theta d\varphi\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\int_{\frac{ab}{a\sin\theta\sin\varphi+b\sin\theta\cos\varphi}}^Rr^3drd\theta d\varphi\end{aligned}

In cylindrical coordinates
$$r(\varphi)=\frac{ab}{a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi}$$ and the integral is
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\frac{ab}{a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi}}^R\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}zrdzdrd\varphi$$

However, I have to deal with a powers of $a\sin\theta\sin\varphi+b\sin\theta\cos\varphi$ and $a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi$ too early, and if I swap the order of integration, I need to express the angles in terms of $r$ which seems worse.

I saw the substitution in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2009918/823281) answer, but it isn't so smooth here and I've seen the [reduction formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3425841).

How should one attack this task?

Comment: have you mistyped the equation of the plane? It says $\frac x a + \frac y a = 1$. Should one of them be $b$ instead of $a$?

Comment: Rotate the plane about z-axis so it is perpendicular to x-axis or y-axis. Then the work is simpler.

Comment: @MathLover, with sadness, I say it is $b$... but I'll try with the rotation. So, the linear transformation with the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\cos\arctan\frac{b}a&\sin\arctan\frac{b}a&0\\-\sin\arctan\frac{b}a&\cos\arctan\frac{b}a&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ should work if I want the plane to be perpendicular to the $y$ axis? And, of course, the sphere is invariant to that rotation, right?

Comment: Yes the sphere is invariant to the rotation.

Comment: I just edited the question to change the equation of the plane to have $y/b$, based on your comment.

Comment: If the $xz$- and $yz$-planes are boundaries of the region, that introduces problems for rotations. (And the $xy$-plane as boundary means the symmetry argument doesn't apply.) They also cut the sphere into multiple different-shaped regions, so are we looking at the first quadrant, or each piece?

Comment: I missed the coordinate planes being the boundary

Comment: Given the coordinate planes being part of the bounds, the rotation will also bring in complication as stated in comments by aschepler. Using cylindrical coordinates and the integral that you have set up seems to me a better way to proceed.

Comment: @aschleper, we're looking in the first quadrant, I should've specified that. In Demidovich, the task was to actually compute the mass, given the density $\rho(x,y,z)=z,$ which is a positive quantity. Thank you for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed in cylindrical coordinates as follows
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{r(\varphi)}^R\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}z \>rdzdrd\varphi\\
= & \> \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{\frac{ab}{a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi}}^R (R^2-r^2)r dr d\varphi\\ 
= & \> \frac12 \int_0^{\pi/2}\left( \frac14R^4–\frac12\frac{a^2b^2R^2}{(a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi)^2}
 + \frac14\frac{a^4b^4}{(a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi)^4 } \right)d\varphi\\ 
 = & \> \frac\pi{16}R^4 -\frac 14abR^2 +\frac1{24}ab(a^2+b^2)\\ 
\end{align}
where
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\varphi}{(a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi)^2} =\frac1{ab}, \>\>\>
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\varphi}{(a\sin\varphi+b\cos\varphi)^4} =\frac{a^2+b^2}{3a^3b^3}$$